# Is a prediction better than an ad/post hoc hypothesis apriori?

Tags: atheism, existence-of-god

Suppose John wins the lottery. Eric, after he wins, claims that he rigged the lottery for John to win. Now imagine an alternative scenario where Eric predicts that John will win and that he claims to have rigged it and then John wins.

Intuitively, the second scenario seems to be better and very good evidence for Eric to have rigged the lottery compared to the first. But why exactly is this the case?

Clearly, it can’t just be the fact that the probability of John winning is low. This would remain the same in both scenarios. Why then exactly is a prediction better evidence?

It seems, atleast to me, that this would only be justified if, in general, riggers who do rig lotteries are more likely to rig it if predicting in advance vs. just claiming to rig it after the fact.

The question then is: **without** this assumption, would a prediction be better evidence? Is there anything **apriori** about a prediction that serves as good evidence for a particular hypothesis or is it purely empirical based on **past** and prior evidence?

Comment: Predictions are more useful than explanations (unless the explanation can be used to make a correct prediction). We like to control things, not just know why our misfortunes occurred.

Comment: The *actual* causal relationships rule the day (see things like Simpson's Paradox - statistically X drug is better, but could be misleading or deadly for a specific person, or Reichenbach's principle "if two observed variables are found to be correlated, then there should be a causal explanation of these correlations"[1]), making neither prediction nor ad/post hoc hypothesis in general better a priori. Wrong causal structure can be from misleading to disastrous. https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09487[1]. You can't choose just one example and reach the conclusion you wish to make. Causes rule all.

Comment: Of course the causal relationship rules all. But the question is how does one determine that there is one? Enough correct predictions? Direct observation? Without direct observation, do we suspend judgment? Or have a belief ?

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is complicated because it introduces the possibility of Eric intentionally lying. That obfuscates the core issue, which is whether a prediction is better than a post-hoc explanation even when people are being honest.

Here's a more pure example concerning that core issue.

Scenario A. A scientist, David, is about to run an experiment. He predicts that the data will fit the curve y = 3x^2 + 1. He runs the experiment and in fact it does fit the curve.

Scenario B. David makes no prediction before running the experiment, but after he runs it, he fits a curve to the data and realizes y = 3x^2 + 1 is a good fit.

Scenario A is obviously much better evidence for the hypothesis H, that if the experiment was run again, the data would again closely fit the curve y = 3x^2 + 1. But why?

In *idealized* Bayesian inference, the probability of H given the experimental data O doesn't depend on when H was proposed. Bayes' law says:

P(H|O) = P(O|H) P(H)/P(O)

In scenario A, the prior probability P(H) shouldn't be any different from scenario B. Nor should the prior probability of the observation, P(O), and nor should P(O|H), and so P(H|O) should be the same in either scenario.

But! In practice, the scientist *does not exactly know P(H)*. But P(H) can be partly estimated by the following heuristic: a hypothesis that *occurs* to the scientist, before the experiment, is more likely (higher prior probability P(H)) than a hypotheses that does not occur to the scientist before the experiment.

So, the fact that in scenario A the scientist has made a prediction, points towards P(H) being legitimately high in scenario A. In scenario B, the fact that the scientist failed to make the prediction points towards P(H) being relatively low, not distinguished from any of the other hypothesis that the scientist didn't predict would happen.

This can be a very large effect. If there are a thousand possible hypotheses initially, the fact that the scientist correctly picked one out of a thousand during the prediction phase is good evidence that there's something special about that particular hypothesis. And that explains why we would expect P(H|O) to be much higher in scenario A than in scenario B.

Comment: What is the hypothesis here? If the hypothesis is that the curve fits the line, then clearly, it fits the line in both cases.

Comment: In each scenario, there is an equal amount of evidence for the curve fitting that line. So I don’t think this gets to the heart of the issue actually.

Comment: @thinkingman I told you what H is : "Scenario A is obviously much better evidence for the hypothesis H, that if the experiment was run again, the data would again closely fit the curve y = 3x^2 + 1." Not that the data fits the curve this particular time, but that there is an underlying principle that would cause this to happen in general when the experiment is run.

Comment: Yes, but is it? If someone after a few trials post hoc notices that previous data fits y=3x^2 + 1, then that has equal evidence to the other scenario for the new data to fit the curve

Comment: I’m going to assume that what you really mean is a hypothesis H where H = “the person who generated the equation knew beforehand what the data would represent.” This is much harder to say, since it would depend on the prior probability of the mechanism in which he knows. Does he claim psychic ability? If so, the evidence might even be arguably the same. Does he claim that he’s observed the data before and he predicts it’ll happen again? In this case, his “discovery” would still be post hoc, but yes, it would serve as better evidence than the other scenario.

Answer (score 0):

People don't judge hypotheses in isolation; they weigh them against other hypotheses.

In this example you're weighing at the very least two hypotheses: that Eric rigged the lottery, and that Eric heard who won it and echoed what he heard (lying about the origin of the information).

The second hypothesis goes from highly implausible to highly plausible in a short time span starting at the point where the future light cone of the lottery drawing intersects Eric's worldline. The absolute plausibility of the first hypothesis may also change, but it doesn't change by nearly enough to prevent a flip in the relative plausibility of the two.